# How can I make my game disable simultaneous taps?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multi-touch

Hi I have a quiz game my problem is when the user tap the three choices at the same time they will always have the right answer, i want to disable that, is it possible? Thanks you.

Answer (score 4):

it depends if you need multitouch for something else, or else you should be able to just do 
`multiTouchEnabled = false;` (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-multiTouchEnabled.html)

You could also in your code disable all input as soon as you register the first touch, so when just one of the buttons gets touched, turn off the collider on all the other buttons.

If this doesn't help we will need to see some code to be able to help.